# Eigenvalues of a linear matrix pencil (Ax = λ Bx) using the subspace iteration method

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

I am trying to find the rightmost eigenvalues of the **generalized eigenvalue problem** ($Ax = \lambda Bx$) using the subspace iteration method. This formulation arises from flow stability analysis where the matrix '**B**' is **singular** and both A and B are **sparse** matrices of the order of **50,000**. I am basically trying to check if the matrix pencil has eigenvalues with a **positive** real part (which means that the flow is unstable to small perturbations), and when it does, I need to know the **imaginary part** of these eigenvalues as it gives the **frequency** of the oscillations.
The idea is to use power iterations (with orthonormalization) to approximate a **subset** of the eigenvectors (**T**). Using these vectors as the basis for an **invariant subspace**, reduced subspace matrices (A' = T<sup>T</sup>A T and B' = T<sup>T</sup>B T) are formed. Then, this reduced dimension eigenvalue problem is solved directly using the QZ algorithm.
The algorithm goes like this -
Step 1: Generate a random set of $m$ orthonormal vectors ($R^{(0)}$), where m is greater than $p$, the number of eigenvalues sought and much less than $n$, the order of the matrices
Step 2: Calculate iteratively $R^{(i+1)} = (A^{-1} B) R^{(i)}$ by solving $AR^{(i+1)} = BR^{(i)}$ and normalize $R$ after every iteration
Step 3: When $\kappa(R)$ increases above a threshold, perform a QR decomposition with $T = R^{new} = Q$
Step 4: Calculate the subspace matrices $A' = T^TA T$ and $B' = T^TB T$
Step 5: Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A'y = \lambda B'y$ using QZ algorithm
Step 6: Recalculate $R$ using $R = Ty$ and go back to Step 2.

This process shall return the smallest eigenvalues of the matrix pencil. In order to get the rightmost eigenvalues, I pre-condition the matrix using **shift-invert transformation**.

The entire algorithm seems to be perfect in theory, but some reflection upon this process made me wonder that the subspace spanned by the eigenvectors of the matrix pencil will not actually be **invariant** under **A** and **B** independently! I consider this to be the reason why the eigenvalues don't converge when I try a sample problem using my code. However, when I choose **B** to be the **identity** matrix, I do get the correct eigenvalues.

Is my reasoning correct, or is there some other source of error in this algorithm?
Upon realizing this issue, I had modified the algorithm with $C = A^{-1}B$ calculated in advance and substituted at all places (It makes $C$ singular but does provide the eigenvalues). However, I am still curious to know if I have identified the issue correctly, and why at all does the algorithm work (it's mentioned in literature), if it is flawed.

Thanks in advance!

**Note**: I am an Engineering undergrad and I studied about invariant subspaces just for the project that I am working on.

Comment: What is your algorithm concerning the power iterations? Anyway, if you randomly choose $A,B$, then they have (with probability $1$) no common invariant subspaces!

Comment: Thank you @loupblanc for your comment. For the power iterations, I start with a random set of orthonormal vectors and repeatedly multiply by A^(-1) B, until the vectors start becoming dependent. Then, I use QR to orthonormalize them again.

I did realize that the subspace won't be invariant under both, but then this was the algorithm that I found in literature. With little experience, I can't claim to disprove it but would like to know what makes this work!

Answer (score 1):

i) $\det(A-\lambda B)=0$ can be rewritten $\det(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}I-A^{-1}B)=0$. You calculate the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}B$ which is the smallest generalized eigenvalue of the pencil $A-\lambda B$.

ii) You calculate $A^{-1}$ (what is the time of calculation ?).

When a matrix is large, it is often ill-condditionned; what is $CN(A)$, the condition number of $A$? If $CN(A)\approx 10^k$, then you must consider $k$ supplementary significant digits along the calculations. Then, calculate $CN(A)$ (there are approximation methods of $CN$ that have complexity $O(n^2)$) before calculating $A^{-1}$.

iii) When you calculate $A^{-1}Bx$, dont calculate $(A^{-1}B)x$, but calculate $A^{-1}(Bx)$, or better,  solve in $y$ the equation $Ay=Bx$ (here, you don't need $A^{-1}$).

EDIT. Answer to the OP.

i) Perhaps you assume that $A,B$ are real symmetric (??); that does not imply that the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$ are real! -except if $A>0$-

ii) If I understand correctly, you obtain (after some iterations) an orthonormal basis of a limit subspace $E$ that is invariant for $A^{-1}B$. Firstly, $E$ is not invariant by $A,B$. Secondly, how do you choose the dimension of $E$ ? Thirdly,
I don't understand why you would get such a limit (especially if there are very close eigenvalues); but let's admit that.

You must write the matrix of $A^{-1}B$ in $E$ -using your orthonormal basis- and diagonalize this matrix. In particular you must calculate explicitly $A^{-1}B$ and you don't work about $A,B$.

iii) Normally, you should only work on $\mathbb{R}$ -the imaginary parts are parasitic; remove them-

About the digits -if you work on the real numbers-

complex*16 works with $16.8=128$ bits, that is,  with $38$ significand digits. Because of $CN(A)$, it remains $38-19=19$ significand digits, that suffices -except if you use complex numbers-

Comment: I am doing precisely the same **(Ay = Bx)** for calculating A^(-1) B. Now, I realized that you had asked about this in your comment (but I hadn't understood your question correctly). And yes, the matrix is ill-conditioned, CN(A) ≈ 1e+19. I am currently using complex*16 in Fortran for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (they tend to be complex). What else can I do to improve the precision?

Comment: You have been really helpful @loupblanc, but I don't have voting privileges yet to upvote your answer (new user here)! In my case, the A matrix isn't symmetric anyway and the imaginary part is important for me as it gives the frequencies. I will make some edits in the question to make it more clear. Also, complex*16 assigns 8 bytes (64 bits) to each part (real and imaginary), which in IEEE standard has 1 sign bit, 11-bit exponent, and a 52-bit fraction. That leaves us with only 16 significant digits. I am using some LAPACK routines which require complex*16, therefore, I cannot use complex*32.

Comment: You can give the green ticket. That means you accept the answer. If you have other questions, open a new file. About the resolution of $Ay=Bx$, you can test an iteration method; yet, you have not any initial point because, by the LU method  -for example-,  you obtain $16-19=-3$  significant digits.

Comment: I am aware of the green tick for accepting an answer but I believe this isn't yet a complete answer to my question. Please check the Subspace Iteration Solution section of [Subspace Iteration Method - Bathe](http://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Publications_Prior_to_1998/Solution_Methods_for_Eigenvalue_Problems_in_Structural_Mechanics.pdf) for an explanation of the algorithm that I am using. I have added more details about my implementation in the question also. If this algorithm is not correct, I wish to know why is it mentioned and used widely in literature.

Comment: Do as you want.